# Transforming dataframe in a for loop

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that I want to transform.

##### Expression Dataframes and Module list

```
gene_express = data.frame(gene = c('gene1', 'gene2', 'gene3', 'gene4', 'gene5', 'gene6', 'gene7', 'gene8', 'gene9', 'gene10'), 
                      sample1 = sample(0:10,10), sample2 = sample(0:10,10), sample3 = sample(0:10,10), sample4 = sample(0:10,10), row.names =1) 
module1 = c('gene1', 'gene2', 'gene10', 'gene8')
module2 = c('gene2', 'gene9', 'gene6', 'gene5', 'gene10')
module3 = c('gene4', 'gene10', 'gene1', 'gene8')
module4 = c('gene5', 'gene8', 'gene2', 'gene7', 'gene6', 
'gene5', 'gene10')
Module_list = list(module1, module2, module3, module4)
names(Module_list) <- c('module1', 'module2', 'module3', 
'module4')
```

##### My code to generate the desire dataframe

```
MASM_mat  = data.frame()
for(module in names(Modules)){
   module_genes = modules[[module]]
   for(column in colnames(gene_express)){
     module_mean  = gene_express[rownames(gene_express) %in% 
     module_gene, ] %>% pull(column) %>% summary()
     module_mean = module_mean[[4]] #this the mean
     module_mean_table = data.frame(module, module_mean) %>% 
     `colnames<-` (c('Module', column))
     MASM_mat = merge(MASM_mat,MASM, all=T)
     }}
```

The result I got from my code:

[image]

My desired result:

[image]

What I want is the mean of each module (i.e an average of the sum of the expression of its component genes from gene_express matrix) in each sample.

Comment: Hi mathew olakunle, wwelcome to SO. It is important to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121) when asking a question. Also, please do not add code as an image for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2530121).This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2530121) has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. Please ensure you include an example of the result you are getting as well as the example of the desired result you have already added. Thanks

Comment: Also, please check your code for errors, your for loop is missing a closing bracket.

Comment: Okay, I will adjust it. Thank you for the enlightenment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df |> 
  mutate(
    module1 = case_match(gene, c("gene1", "gene2", "gene8", "gene10") ~ TRUE, .default = FALSE),
    module2 = case_match(gene, c("gene2", "gene9", "gene6", "gene5", "gene10") ~ TRUE, .default = FALSE),
    module3 = case_match(gene, c("gene4", "gene10", "gene1", "gene8") ~ TRUE, .default = FALSE),
    module4 = case_match(gene, c("gene5", "gene2", "gene7", "gene8", "gene6", "gene10") ~ TRUE, .default = FALSE)
  ) |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("module"),
               names_to = "Module",
               values_to = "blnModule") |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("sample"),
               names_to = "numSample",
               values_to = "sample") |> 
  filter(blnModule == TRUE) |> 
  summarise(mean = mean(sample), .by = c(Module, numSample)) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = numSample,
              values_from = mean) |> 
  arrange(Module)
```

This would result in

```
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  Module  sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4
  <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 module1    1.68    2.9     3.58    4.25
2 module2    3.5     3.86    4.06    1.6 
3 module3    1.92    4.82    4.92    4.5 
4 module4    2.42    3.22    3.05    2.17
```

when using the sample data

```
> df
     gene sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4
1   gene1     1.2     1.3     5.0       7
2   gene2     5.0     2.3     1.3       1
3   gene3     9.0     4.0     4.5       9
4   gene4     6.0    10.0     6.7       2
5   gene5     6.0     0.0     3.0       2
6   gene6     3.0     7.0     4.0       0
7   gene7     0.0     2.0     2.0       1
8   gene8     0.0     1.0     1.0       8
9   gene9     3.0     3.0     5.0       4
10 gene10     0.5     7.0     7.0       1
```

Comment: You are welcome. However, "thank you"-comments should be avoided on SO. If this answer helps you, you can vote on it. If your question is answered, you can accept the answer.

Comment: I am much new to stack overflow and I cant vote yet and I dont know how to accept the solution

Comment: if I have 100s of modules, can I loop through with this solution? I am working with gene expression and 100s of pathways (modules). How can I scale the solution?

Comment: Yes, if you have more modules, you can attach them to your data frame e.g. such that it looks like above (every module one column). The rest should then work automatically.

Comment: I mean what you put inside the mutate function. I cannot manually specify 100s of modules as you did here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257278/discussion-between-mathew-olakunle-and-jan).

Answer (score 0):

I have the following solution using dplyr and purrr packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# First, I need to create an example list

## Define function to create datasets
create_dataframe <- function() {
  data <- matrix(runif(n = 40, min = 1, max = 10), nrow = 10)
  colnames(data) <- c("sample1", "sample2", "sample3", "sample4")
  as_tibble(data)
}

## Create list with datasets and add names
data_list <- set_names(map(1:3, ~create_dataframe() %>% 
                             mutate(gene = paste0("gene", row_number()))),
                       paste0("module", 1:3))
```

The contents of the list are going to look as follows:

```
## View the names and contents of the list
data_list

$module1
# A tibble: 10 × 5
   sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 gene  
     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr> 
 1    7.31    9.53    7.74    2.49 gene1 
 2    3.12    5.06    4.22    5.47 gene2 
 3    7.82    4.06    6.57    7.18 gene3 
 4    9.64    7.99    9.62    4.66 gene4 
 5    4.41    1.01    7.52    9.53 gene5 
 6    4.74    6.00    5.79    8.09 gene6 
 7    3.62    1.36    8.72    3.71 gene7 
 8    3.98    3.46    2.00    5.89 gene8 
 9    8.17    6.75    3.89    2.58 gene9 
10    8.84    2.31    4.59    8.22 gene10

$module2
# A tibble: 10 × 5
   sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 gene  
     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr> 
 1    3.09    8.61    5.42    4.32 gene1 
 2    4.27    1.85    2.52    9.57 gene2 
 3    2.97    1.56    5.87    1.21 gene3 
 4    6.00    1.74    7.14    3.83 gene4 
 5    9.14    3.85    6.96    2.16 gene5 
 6    2.22    7.87    2.04    1.56 gene6 
 7    4.76    1.34    6.52    8.02 gene7 
 8    3.12    2.42    6.58    8.80 gene8 
 9    1.98    9.54    8.79    9.37 gene9 
10    6.00    2.81    8.44    8.22 gene10

$module3
# A tibble: 10 × 5
   sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 gene  
     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr> 
 1    2.77    4.33    7.45    4.70 gene1 
 2    6.21    3.65    3.15    8.31 gene2 
 3    3.82    3.14    8.54    6.11 gene3 
 4    9.24    5.29    6.03    3.63 gene4 
 5    1.39    2.09    2.12    4.68 gene5 
 6    2.78    7.54    4.95    6.90 gene6 
 7    1.84    2.77    2.50    3.31 gene7 
 8    1.19    9.62    8.28    3.83 gene8 
 9    3.59    5.71    3.80    4.99 gene9 
10    8.28    7.47    6.02    1.49 gene10
```

Now that I have the data you described, we can try to summarize it per each column and per each dataframe preserving the "modules" names in our final dataframe:

```
# Second, we can try to solve the problem

## 1. Add name as a column to each dataframe
data_summary <- map2_df(data_list, names(data_list), ~mutate(.x, module = .y)) %>%
  ## 2. Group per each module
  group_by(module) %>% 
  ## 3. Obtain the mean for each numeric column per each module
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~ mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

That will give us:

```
# View the resulting dataframe
data_summary

# A tibble: 3 × 5
  module  sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4
  <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 module1    6.17    4.75    6.06    5.78
2 module2    4.35    4.16    6.03    5.71
3 module3    4.11    5.16    5.29    4.79
```

### Steps explanation

In the step `## 1.` we are basically iterating per each element in the list to get the list name and putting it as a column. You can try to run just that line before the pipe and print it:

```
data_summary <- map2_df(data_list, names(data_list), ~mutate(.x, module = .y))
glimpse(data_summary)

Rows: 30
Columns: 6
$ sample1 <dbl> 7.310013, 3.116367, 7.824866, 9.640641, 4.412526, …
$ sample2 <dbl> 9.525970, 5.061090, 4.061504, 7.992823, 1.005762, …
$ sample3 <dbl> 7.736501, 4.221009, 6.572459, 9.617854, 7.521257, …
$ sample4 <dbl> 2.494732, 5.472572, 7.175298, 4.658211, 9.528062, …
$ gene    <chr> "gene1", "gene2", "gene3", "gene4", "gene5", "gene…
$ module  <chr> "module1", "module1", "module1", "module1", "modul…
```

That dataframe contains all the observations of the 3 modules with the new column that identifies where each observation came from. From here, we can group by each `module` category (step `## 2.`).

Then, we want to obtain the mean pear each numeric column, which is step `## 3.`

Comment: Thank you, @ronnyale, for your detailed explanation. But I think you lost me because my problem seems a bit different. I have a data frame with genes in the row and Samples in the column. I have a list of Modules. Each module has a list of genes. I aim to take each module and calculate the mean of its component genes per each sample.  Note each module consists of different lengths of genes. But you started with a dataframe of Modules, which confuses me.